# How to set intervals between multiple requests AWS Lambda API

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I have created an API using AWS Lambda function (using Python). Now my react js code hits this API whenever an event fire. So user can request API as many times the events are fired. Now the problem is we are not getting the response from lambda API sequentially. Sometime we are getting the response of our last request faster than the previous response of previous request.
So we need to handle our response in Lambda function sequentially, may be adding some delay between 2 request or may be implementing throttling. So how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQS FIFO Queue as a trigger on the Lambda function, set Batch size to 1, and the Reserved Concurrency on the Function to 1. The messages will always be processed in order and will not concurrently poll the next message until the previous one is complete.

SQS triggers do not support Batch Window - which will 'wait' until polling the next message. This is a feature for Stream based Lambda triggers (Kinesis and DynamoDB Streams)

If you want to streamlined process, Step Function will let you manage states using state machines and supports automatic retry based off the outputs of individual states.

Comment: Thank you. I have set the SQS and triggered it to my lambda function. But how to change the batch size, currently it is showing 10

Comment: You will have to delete the trigger and recreate it while setting the Batch size to 1. This can be done from the Lambda console.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the concurrency setting on Lambda? You can throttle the lambda there.

But if you throttle the lambda and the requests being sent are not being received, the application sending the requests might be receiving an error unless you are storing the requests somewhere on AWS for being processed later.

I think putting an SQS in front of lambda might help. You will be hitting API gateway, the requests get sent to SQS, lambda polls requests concurrently (you can control the concurrency) and then send the response back.

Comment: can we do something in our react js code ,like to send the request with little delay until the previous response is not received

Answer (score 0):

As a previous response said, potentially what could help is to put an SQS in front of the Lambda - if order of processing is important, you could also look at setting the SQS queue up as a FIFO queue, which preserves order:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html

As the other comment said, the other option is to limit concurrency, but even then you're probably best off putting SQS in front as you're then limiting your throughput.